# returning array results after in_array check?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to read in a file that has HTML list items with ++++ as delimeters. Basically, I am trying to search through each item in the array for the text of "nmb" (which is stored in the class) and then display all of the items IN the array that have "nmb".  However, my current code does not work. It displays... NOTHING.  And gives no errors.  What am I missing here?

```
<?php
$term = "nmb";
$f_contents = file_get_contents("../includes/inc-condo-list.php"); //get the entire file
$array = explode("++++",$f_contents); //explode (create an array) seperated by new line elements
$datotal = count($array);  //gives me a TOTAL count.. maybe for later use


foreach ($array as $str ){    //go through each item in array
    if(!in_array($term, $array)) {
    echo $str;
    }
}

unset ($array);

?>
```

Here is an example of the list items being brought in from reading the file.

```
  ++++
    <li class="condo mb"> <a class="condos" href="blah.html"> <img src="someimg.jpg" alt="Narf" /></a> <br />
     <a class="condos" href="somewhere.html">Some Link</a><br />
        4 &amp; 6 Bedrooms<br />

</li>
    ++++
  <li class="condo nmb"> <a class="condos" href="blah.html"> <img src="someimg.jpg" alt="Narf" /></a> <br />
     <a class="condos" href="somewhere.html">Some Link</a><br />
        4 &amp; 6 Bedrooms<br />

</li>
    ++++
```

Any help would be MORE than appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`in_array` looks for an exact value match. Use something like this instead.

```
foreach ($array as $str ){    //go through each item in array
    if(strpos($str, $term) === false) { // if it's not present
        echo $str;
    }
}
```

Comment: And you're looking for it in the entire array, once for each element of said array.

Comment: Not quite sure I get what you mean, could you re-phrase that? :)

Comment: Of course - your exploded value would be an array with an element for every section between `++++`s. `in_array` looks for `$term` in every element in the given array (and so would look in every section). In essence, the answer to `!in_array($term, $array)` would be the same regardless of how many times through the loop you go. Did I make any sense then? (When I say you - I mean the OP).

Comment: Oh, gotcha - yes, I just corrected that because he was just checking the wrong thing. I wasn't the main problem, but it definitely wasn't helping :P

Comment: Thanks Joe! Smooth as silk. :) And thank you Adam as well for that clarification.